# Оборот с "благодаря" поясняющий?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Благодаря своей смышлености(,) ему удавалось делать то, в чем были бессильны зрячие, а слепота не была ему помехой даже при игре в шахматы и нарды.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?
Правила прочитал, но не могу понять, является ли оборот с "благодаря" поясняющим (в таком случае с запятой).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном предложении оборот желательно выделить (это **смысловое** выделение оборота):

***Благодаря своей смышлЁности,** // ему удавалось делать то, в чем были бессильны зрячие, //а слепота не была ему помехой даже при игре в шахматы и нарды.*

В то же время нужно учитывать контекст. Если тема «смышлености» была начата ранее, то можно обойтись и без обособления, в противном же случае этот факт желательно **подчеркнуть.**

**Пояснение**

1. Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов **факультативное** (авторское), причем оно зависит от ряда факторов: смысловое выделение,  **пояснительное значение (обычно уточняются какие-то детали)**,  позиции оборота,  распространенность (самого оборота и предложения) и т.д. Важен и контекст, об этом не стоит забывать.

В конечном счете мы решаем две задачи:  хотим ли мы выделить оборот при обособлении  и можем ли это сделать, учитывая структуру предложения.

2. Производный предлог БЛАГОДАРЯ имеет значение **причины** (обычно с положительным результатом). В начале предложения **причинное значение оборота будет подчеркнуто** (это смысловое выделение, не пояснительное).

**Розенталь** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

1. **Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения** могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами),
2. Чаще всего обособленные обстоятельственные конструкции образуются существительными с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями: **благодаря**, ввиду и др.

Во многих случаях обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление **факультативно**.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение, некоторые моменты мне и в голову не пришли.